# tuning hyperparameters using bayesian optimisation, optimiser not recognised

Tags: keras, deep-learning, neural-network, hyperparameters

I am using Baesian optimisation to tune my model however however I am getting an error for all the optimisers. here is my code:

```py
# Create function
from keras.layers import BatchNormalization
from keras.optimizers import Ftrl as LegacyNadam 
def nn_cl_bo2(neurons, activation, optimizer, learning_rate, batch_size, epochs,
              layers1, layers2, normalization, dropout, dropout_rate):
    optimizerL = ['SGD', 'Adam', 'RMSprop', 'Adadelta', 'Adagrad', 'Adamax', 'Nadam', 'Ftrl','SGD']
    optimizerD= {'Adam':Adam(learning_rate=learning_rate), 'SGD':SGD(learning_rate=learning_rate),
                 'RMSprop':RMSprop(learning_rate=learning_rate), 'Adadelta':Adadelta(learning_rate=learning_rate),
                 'Adagrad':Adagrad(learning_rate=learning_rate), 'Adamax':Adamax(learning_rate=learning_rate),
                 'Nadam':Nadam(learning_rate=learning_rate), 'Ftrl':Ftrl(learning_rate=learning_rate)}
    activationL = ['relu', 'sigmoid', 'softplus', 'softsign', 'tanh', 'selu',
                   'elu', 'exponential','relu']
    neurons = round(neurons)
    activation = activationL[round(activation)]
    optimizer = optimizerD[optimizerL[round(optimizer)]]
    batch_size = round(batch_size)
    epochs = round(epochs)
    layers1 = round(layers1)
    layers2 = round(layers2)
    def nn_cl_fun():
        nn = Sequential()
        nn.add(Dense(neurons, input_dim=30, activation=activation))
        if normalization > 0.5:
            nn.add(BatchNormalization())
        for i in range(layers1):
            nn.add(Dense(neurons, activation=activation))
        if dropout > 0.5:
            nn.add(Dropout(dropout_rate, seed=123))
        for i in range(layers2):
            nn.add(Dense(neurons, activation=activation))
        nn.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
        nn.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizer, metrics=['accuracy'])
        return nn
    es = EarlyStopping(monitor='accuracy', mode='max', verbose=0, patience=20)
    nn = KerasClassifier(model=nn_cl_fun, epochs=epochs, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=0)
    kfold = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=5, shuffle=True, random_state=123)
    score = cross_val_score(nn, X_train, y_train, scoring=score_acc, cv=kfold, fit_params={'callbacks':[es]}).mean()
    return score
```

This is where I pass my parameters

```py
params_nn2 ={
    'neurons': (10, 100),
    'activation':(0, 8),
    'optimizer':(0,6),
    'learning_rate':(0.01, 1),
    'batch_size':(200, 1000),
    'epochs':(20, 100),
    'layers1':(1,3),
    'layers2':(1,3),
    'normalization':(0,1),
    'dropout':(0,1),
    'dropout_rate':(0,0.3)
}
# Run Bayesian Optimization
nn_bo = BayesianOptimization(nn_cl_bo2, params_nn2, random_state=111)
nn_bo.maximize(init_points=25, n_iter=4)
```

this is my error message

> KeyError: 'The optimizer cannot recognize variable dense_5585/kernel:0. This usually means you are trying to call the optimizer to update different parts of the model separately. Please call `optimizer.build(variables)` with the full list of trainable variables before the training loop or use legacy optimizer `tf.keras.optimizers.legacy.Nadam.'

I get this same error for all optimiser types that I have inputted above